# Firebase database deleted when added app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Okay, so I am building an app that will go on the play store, it has the facility to add data to the Firebase (it cannot read it).

Second app will remain with me, (it wont go on the play store) and it is used to read the data.

Now what I did was, lets say the first app has package name : `com.example.write` and the second has `com.example.read`.

So I went to Firebase, created a project, added an application using the package name `com.example.write` and setup my first app. Working perfectly, I could add data to the Firebase database, now to create the second app, I created the android studio project, using the package name `com.example.read` and as both the apps use the same Firebase database, I added the new app in the same project in firebase, with package name `com.example.read` but then what I noticed was the previous database was deleted and when I hit the database button on the navigation bar, it gives me an option to create a database, when I do so, the first app crashes (probably because the old database was deleted to it could not add the data properly). So what should i do to use the same database on both the apps?

Using spark (free) plan of firebase!

Comment: The Firebase console shows setup options even when there is data already when using a slow Internet connection. Refresh console page and check your Internet connection. If that doesn't resolve your issue, please share some code where you are setting and fetching data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So what should i do to use the same database on both the apps ?

To solve this, open [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), select your project, then click on `Add another app` and select `Add Firebase to your Android app`.

Provide all the necessary details for the new package name, in your case `com.example.read`, then download the JSON file again and add it to **both** of your android apps that are connected to this project. That's it!

Comment: But imagine my app is live on the play store, and i decided to add another app, then to add that json to the live app, i'll have to roll out an update, so until the user updates the app, the app is basically useless ?

Comment: Yes, you need to add the JSON file to that app too. Both app should have the same JSON file.

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: Everything perfect! Thanks a ton!